# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException? Java Package program can't compile

Tags: java

I'm getting an error when compiling my java code. The error is:

```
Enter the length in centimeters: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at Package.main(Package.java:11)
```

Code from http://jsfiddle.net/tzxzawxp/;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Package
{   
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
double length;
double width;
double height;
System.out.print("Enter the length in centimeters: ");
length = reader.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the width in centimeters: ");
width = reader.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the height in centimeters: ");
height = reader.nextDouble();

if (length <=0 | width <=0 | height <=0)
System.out.println("Invalid");
else
{
if (length < 10 && width < 10 && height < 10)
{
System.out.println ("Accept");
System.out.println("Volume is " + (length * width * height) + "cm");
System.out.println("Length is " + length);
System.out.println("Width is " + width);
System.out.println("Height is " + height);
if (length > 10 | width > 10 | height > 10)
System.out.println ("Reject");

}
}
}
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: For such little code, always post it directly in the question. Also, you don't get any error *compiling* the code, you get a run-time error when *running* it.

Answer (score 0):

It throws `NoSuchElementException` in line 11 -> `length = reader.nextDouble();`
It is pretty straightforward, it can't read a new double from the standard input. Are you sure you are passing those parameters through stdin?

Note: that is an excecution problem, the code does compile correctly

According to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()

Throws NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am new to java. Can you elaborate what you mean by passing those parameters through stdin?

Comment: Are you getting those parameters from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues, for one `Reject` will never output the way you have your logic nested.

let's start with reading the input (note: do not close a `Scanner` wrapped around `System.in` - it's a global),

```
double[] values = new double[3];
String[] fields = { "length", "width", "height" };
int pos = 0;
while (pos < values.length) {
    String field = fields[pos];
    System.out.printf("Enter the %s in centimeters: ", field);
    System.out.flush();
    if (!reader.hasNext()) {
        System.err.println("Nothing available from reader.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (reader.hasNextDouble()) {
        values[pos++] = reader.nextDouble();
    } else {
        System.err.printf("%s is not a double.%n", reader.next());
    }
}
```

Also please use braces, and boolean or is `||` (not `|`). So something like,

```
double length = values[0];
double width = values[1];
double height = values[2];
// if (length <= 0 | width <= 0 | height <= 0)
if (length <= 0 || width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
} else {
    if (length < 10 && width < 10 && height < 10) {
        System.out.println("Accept");
        System.out.println("Volume is " + (length * width * height)
                + "cm");
        System.out.println("Length is " + length);
        System.out.println("Width is " + width);
        System.out.println("Height is " + height);
    } else { // if (length > 10 | width > 10 | height > 10)
        System.out.println("Reject");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code in eclipse, no exception is thrown while running the program.
Please try in eclipse once which is best way to learn.

Hope you it will run without exceptions.

**My output:**

Enter the length in centimeters: 0.3
Enter the width in centimeters: 0.4
Enter the height in centimeters: 0.5
Accept
Volume is 0.06cm
Length is 0.3
Width is 0.4
Height is 0.5